# required:true working in one place but not in another on same form [Rails form_for]

Tags: class, form-for, required

= form_for @apps do |f|

```
= f.label :bank_name_branch
= f.select :bank_name_branch, current_department.bank_infos.map { |src| [(src.bank_name+", "+src.branch), (src.bank_name+","+src.branch)] }, { prompt: "#{t('select-one')}" }, required: true, class:"w-100"

= f.label :kista_type
= f.select :kista_type, current_department.kista_types.map {|kistaType| [kistaType.kista_name, kistaType.kista_name]}, prompt: "#{t('select-one')}", required: true, class:"w-100"
```

Problem is that required:true is working with :bank_name_branch but not with :kista_type. Couldn't find what is the problem?

Already tried:- Refreshing my server, browser, :required=>true

Answer (score 0):

Would you add them to your form Model?

like

```
class YourClass < ApplicationRecord

   validates :bank_name_branch, presence: true
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :bank_name_branch
```

Should appear on your form like this:

> Branch Name *

Comment: Thanks. I have done that in my model but i want it in the browser as well so that browser need not reload for the errors display. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried collection_select instead of select? Something like:

```
= f.collection_select(:bank_name_branch, @bank_name_branch, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select', required: true)
```

i.e    `= collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`